# How to add extra fields outside the list of items in modelView ? (like count for pagination)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for the best way to add additional fields to the get list return of a ModelView.

I have the following model:

```py
class Sale(models.Model):
    total = models.FloatField(_("Total"))
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"))
    [...]
```

When I do a get list on this model, I get the following json:

```json
{

    "count": 0,
    "next": "http://example.com",
    "previous": "http://example.com",
    "results": 
    [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "example",
            "total": 0,
            [...]
         }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add 2 fields min_total and max_total to the result (at the same level as "count").

Example:

```json
{

    "count": 0,
    "next": "http://example.com",
    "previous": "http://example.com",
    "min_total": 0,
    "max_total": 100,
    "results": 

    [
        {

            "id": 0,
            "name": "example",
            "total": 100,
            [...]
         }
    ]
}
```

My View:

```py
class SaleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving sales.
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filter_fields = ['client', 'machine', 'date_time', 'total']
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'action') and self.action == 'list':
            return SaleListSerializer
        if hasattr(self, 'action') and self.action == 'retrieve':
            return SaleRetrieveSerializer
        return SaleSerializer  
       
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Sale.objects.all().select_related('client')
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_staff:
            cache_key = 'list_sale_sales'
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(client=user.profil.client)
            cache_key = f'list_sale_sales_client_{user.profil.client.pk}'
        
        return cache.get_or_set(cache_key, queryset, 60)
```

To get these 2 values I just have to make these 2 requests:
`Sale.objects.all().aggregate(min=Min("total"))` and `Sale.objects.all().aggregate(max=Max("total"))`

What is the best method to add these 2 fields properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the list method of viewset:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    response.data['min_total'] = Sale.objects.all().aggregate(min=Min("total"))
    response.data['max_total'] = Sale.objects.all().aggregate(max=Max("total"))
    return response
```

**Note**: This will give min/max value from all Sale records. To get min/max value from filtered data based on your `get_queryset` function:

```
response.data['min_total'] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(min=Min("total"))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me.
However, how to integrate these 2 fields to the serializers? 
I can't add `min_total = serializers.IntegerField()` otherwise they are not placed outside results.  EDIT: I just test, it's works ... I don't know how it's possible ^^ I will search by myself. thank you

Comment: Cool! Well, we are just appending `min_total` and `max_total` with the paginated response by overriding the list method of `viewset`. Do let me know if I can be of further help. If this answer helped you to solve your problem, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a extra field outside the result list in Viewsets

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    paginated_response = super(SaleViewSet, self).get_paginated_response(data)
    response = paginated.data
    """ write your code here for adding extra field"""
    return Response(response)
```

by overriding get_paginated_response(self, data) method you can easily add any extra field, variable paginated_response return API Response object, and variable response return actual response of an API

> NOTE- response variable return data in Ordered dict, So you can easily add your extra field